# QGIS 2.18.9 for Windows will not load plugins and GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass

Hi I've been using QGIS for the past 6 years and I have never had this issue. I re-installed QGIS 2.18.9 because my original first problem was none of my grass algorithms would work and I received the following error message:

```
"It seems that GRASS GIS 7 is not correctly installed and configured in your system. Please install it before running GRASS GIS 7 algorithms."
```

I tried this solution [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197510/qgis-cant-run-any-grass-tools-from-processing-toolbox), but no luck.

My next issue is once I re-installed QGIS none of my plugins will load. Heres what the error message log shows:
[image: Error1][image: Error2]

I have gone into both of the QGIS plugins and Python site-packages and everything is there even though it states that it is not.

What could be my issue?

Answer (score 0):

So doing a simple un-install then re-install of QGIS would not work, since for what ever reason why the **msys** file wasn't being installed where the processing options said it was.

The Trick was to:

```
delete qgis from the registry
```